# Download manager with import

Tags: download

I have a big list of URL's that I want to download, BUT each file needs to be downloaded to a specific filename + directory. But all download managers I tried can only import a list of URL's, but cannot specify a filename..

Comment: Have you looked at jDownloader? I believe it may contain this feature.

Comment: @Carl: Unfortunately it doesn't. All it can do is sort into separate directories, not rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wget can take any arbitrary URL to download, and it can take any arbitrary output pathname in `-O`. Just call it in a loop with the values you care about.

Comment: @EBGreen: "Wise" doesn't always mean "optimal".

Comment: I agree, however the comment was from the OP and the nature of the comment implied that it was the solution that was used. Just trying to help a new user get into the habits that make a good Stack Exchange user.

Comment: Hey im not a SA newbie ;) But I was just reading through answers at work till I had more time to check them all out..

Answer (score 0):

[aria2](http://aria2.sf.net) can do what you want, you just have to format the [input file](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/aria2c.1.html#_input_file) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You should try with Internet Download Manager(IDM) it has many good options and it's feature of Queue will allow you download one by one automatically after adding the url in it. And it makes folder under the My Document folder "Downloads" where you will get more folder's in manage way like Video, Music, Program and Compressed folder the item automatically downloaded in the desired folder by it. It can integrated with most of the available browser's. NAd it recognize the  format automatically of the item so you have no need to give the directory name for each item separately.